# Phalcon 4.0 setting up Session

Tags: session, dependency-injection, phalcon

I am trying to make an session in my phalcon project, version 4.0 but I am getting this error while creating an session.

> Class 'Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files' not found

```
$di->setShared('session',function(){
    $session = new \Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files();
    $session->start();
    return $session;
});
```

If someone knows a method in which I can create an session please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

this seemed to work for me

```
 $di->setShared('session',function(){
        $session = new Phalcon\Session\Manager();
        $files = new Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Stream( [
            'savePath' => '/tmp',
        ]);
        $session->setAdapter($files)->start();
        return $session;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files` class was renamed to `Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Stream` in Phalcon 4.0.0

[check the documentation](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/upgrade#session-1) for other issues you could run into if you recently upgraded

if you copied that code from the documentation then its for Phalcon 3.4.x